# Eclipse import Phonegap project

Tags: eclipse, cordova, command-line-interface

I have the HTML/JS/config.xml files of an app that was built using online phonegap build. How can I import these files into a project that I can work on with Eclipse/Phonegap CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here is all you need, just follow the steps.
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: This is how to start with a new project. I need to know how to "import" and existing project that was built using the web version of phonegap build to the eclipse/cli format.

Comment: create a new project like that, add android platform (with cli), copy your files from the old one, then call cordova prepare cli command prompt function.

Answer (score 0):

**First you will need to create a new project using your existing HTML/JS/CSS/icons**

- put your files in a folder, let's say c:\oldproject
- create a new cordova project using the CLI and tell it to import your existing files (replace foldername, com.test.app and TestApp  with proper values)

  cordova create foldername com.test.app TestApp --copy-from=c:\oldproject

**Replace phonegap.js reference with cordova.js**

In index.html, replace the inclusion of phonegap.js with cordova.js (note that you may choose to use phonegap CLI instead of cordova CLI to create/build the project, in that case, you could continue to use phonegap.js)

**Then put back the config and add plugins**

- replace the generated config.xml in the project with the one of your old project
- If your config.xml contains plugins (lines begining with `<gap:plugin`) you will have to use the CLI to add each plugin.

For example if you have the line

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"
```

you would have to call

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

**Then you have to add the android platform and build the project.**

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

**Now your project is ready to be imported in eclipse.**

Please note that I don't really see any interest in using eclipse now that you can build projects using CLI. (I personnaly use a text editor that handles javascrit much better than eclipse and then do everything with the CLI).

**Final warning**

If you edit code in eclipse, you will be editing files in platforms/android/assets/www/, not in /www folder.

If you use the cli commands `cordova build android` or `cordova prepare android`, the CLI will take the content of the root www folder and put it in platforms/android/assets/www, so all your changes will be lost.

So if you choose to use eclipse to edit javascript/CSS, you will have to choose either save your changes to the root www folder before you use the CLI or stop using the CLI (so if you want to add a plugin you'd have to use plugman).